# How to execute a function after arrow down then enter is pressed?

Tags: jquery

I need to execute a function when a user FIRST press arrow down (to make sure that the user is goes down to ui-autocomplete) THEN enter. Any suggestions? This is my current code:

```
count = 0;
$('#this_is_input').keyup(function(e) {
    // I need to make sure the user hit arrow down before executing the $('.submitBtn').click();
    if (e.keyCode == 13) {
        // First enter pressed
        if(count == 0) { 
            $('.submitBtn').click();
            CONFIRM_LOCATION.attr('disabled', 'disabled');
        }
        count++;
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

If you just need to intercept the `downArrowKey` just before the `enter` key, you could save the qualifying `downArrowKey` condition to a `global` variable and check it's value along with `enter` key.

```
var count = 0;
var downArrowPressed = false;
$('#this_is_input').keyup(function(e) {
   if(e.keyCode != 13) {
   downArrowPressed = e.keyCode == 40 ? true : false; }
   console.log(downArrowPressed);
      //  downArrowPressed = true;
    // I need to make sure the user hit arrow down before executing the $('.submitBtn').click();
    if (e.keyCode == 13 && downArrowPressed) {
        // First enter pressed
        if(count == 0) 
        { 
            downArrowPressed = false;
            alert('Submit');
           // $('.submitBtn').click();
           // CONFIRM_LOCATION.attr('disabled', 'disabled');
        }
     //   count++;
    }
});
```

Example : https://jsfiddle.net/DinoMyte/up4j39qr/9/